# Using an NSPredicate to access self.items

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

For various reasons (summarized at the end) I am experimenting with using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to return some `NSManagedObjects`.

Specifically, a `Person` has many `Cars`, modeled using the core data relationship cars. I want to add another method to `Person` to return the same cars as self.cars, but using a FRC.

I think I am making a basic error with my `NSPredicate`, which is designed to only find the cars where `car.person == self`:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateAdded" ascending:YES];


 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
   [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person == '%@'", self];
   [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

   NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                  managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                  sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                  cacheName:nil];
   NSError *error;
   BOOL success = [controller performFetch:&error];
```

No cars are being returned at all. Is my predicate incorrect?

*Side Note - why not just use self.cars?*
Like I say this is an experiment. I am hoping to benefit from the persistent cache of an `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes in the predicate.

Comment: That did it. Care to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes in the predicate are wrong, it should be

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person == %@", self];
```

Answer (score 1):

In the example you are fetching `"Person"` objects. Maybe you want to fetch `"Car"` objects instead?

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Car"];
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in the example - I have corrected it. Thanks.